# Non-convergent sequence multiplied by a sequence with a zero limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let ($t_n$)
be a sequence which converges to $0$: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n=0  $$ Let ($s_n$) be a sequence which is bounded both from above and below. 
Show
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n s_n=0  $$

I'm not totally sure how to approach this problem.  Because $s_n$ doesn't necessarily have a limit I've tried approaching it by bringing up the definitions of boundedness but I'm a little lost.  What would be the best starting point to go for here?

Comment: The boundedness condition just means $\forall n,\ a\le s_n\le b$ for some constants $a,b$. Also if $c$ is a constant $c\,t_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

[Squeeze Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) 
$$
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
$$

Comment: So you'd suggest using this to prove that (sn) has a limit?  I think I know how to solve it from there thanks!

Comment: No, $\{s_n\} $ does not have to be convergent.